# How to upload photos on Instagram via C#

Tags: c#, upload, instagram, webrequest, instasharp

so thats my challange:
try to upload a photo to instagram via you PC.

I didn't want to use the official API from Instagram and i know that they may bann me.

I googled arround and found the "InstaSharp" lib. https://github.com/Codeusa/InstaSharp. My problem here is that i can't logging in. I get the follow Error Code:
Error while logging Your version of Instagram is out of date. Please upgrade your app to log in to Instagram.

So i checked up the library code and find a "userAgent" string. I installed bluestack, Fiddle 4 and ProxyCap to "scan" the https request and checked out that there is a new userAgent string. So i changed the string to the follow line: "Instagram 9.4.0 Android (19/4.4.2; 160dpi; 1080x1920; asus; ASUS_T00J; ASUS_T00J; redhookbay; de_DE)". 
But the result is the same :(.

Does anyone know's what's wrong here?
Or have an idea what i could do?

And no, i didn't want to create a bot or something like that but sharing stuff on Instagram via smartphone is very very.... I knows grambl & Co but didn't like the interface. I only want a smart tool to upload images and set some tags.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: _"Help me write a client for Service X that bypasses their checks for genuine clients"_ is too broad.

Comment: Its not possible to upload from third party apps without using its API. Only workaround is a bot. So what do you want actually?

Comment: I just want to upload Photos without the app so that i can upload directly from my pc. It must be possible, or how do it gramblr & co?